# What data type is best for store points in Redis?

Tags: redis

There are two buttons on web page: `like` and `unlike`.
When user click to these buttons does query that counters number of clicks.
What is best and user usable data type in Redis to store it?

I have some options:

- use `increment key`
- use `hash` with one field count and key of button ID
- use `sortet sets`

Problem is that I want to show users names who pushed button and number of clicks.

Comment: Do you need rankings? What do you want to achieve, performance on reads / low size in memory?

Comment: I need fast read deom memory and do easy increment value. I can use sorted set, but it will generate a lot sets for eash note:                     `$key = 'reposts:news:200';
$time = time();
$this->redis->zadd($key, $time, array());`

Comment: Imagine I have a 10 millions kinds of notes in Redis. For each I can set LIKE. If used sortedset I will have create 10 millions `sets`

Comment: Do you need rankings from redis? Do you want to get first 10 users or similar features?